# "Class not found" error when attempting to access inbuilt DateTime class

Tags: blocks, 8

I am attempting to convert a working Drupal 6 module to Drupal 8 in preparation for the up coming release, and as an exercise in learning the new system.

In my existing module, I do some calculations on whether or not it is currently the weekend or a weekday and output some HTML in a block based on that.

In my code I have a `is_weekend()` function which returns `TRUE` if it is currently the weekend, and `FALSE` if it is a weekday.

My code for that function starts like this.

```
function is_weekend() {
  $ESTTZ = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
  $dt = new DateTime();
  $dt->setTimezone($ESTTZ);
  $day = $dt->format("w");
  $hour = $dt->format("H");
  $minute = $dt->format("i");
  $weekend = FALSE;

  if ($day == 6) {
    // ...
  }

  return $weekend;
}
```

It works fine; however, when I try to put this function into my new block class I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\livequotes\Plugin\Block\DateTimeZone' not found in C:\Work\ex-global-8

How can I call this PHP class from within my own block class?

Comment: Every PHP builtin classes are defined in the root namespace. How to reference a builtin class from inside a namespace is not specific for Drupal; it is done in Drupal as it is done in plain PHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're just running into namespace problems. `DateTimeZone` is in the root namespace, so refer to it as:

```
\DateTimeZone
```

Same for

```
\DateTime
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. One of the things that I am looking forward to from Drupal 8 is upgrading my OOP skills. I suspect I have an awful lot to learn though!

Comment: This here is just one of the idio(t)syncrasies of PHP.

Comment: thank you sir, I was going insane with this